# Remove query string to Yii URL

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

In Yii1.x all we had to do was add path something like'

```
urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path', 
    .............
)
```

But in Yii2 its gone. How do I make my URLs without query-string something like
`http://example.com/forum/post/id/2014/make-yii2-work`

**EDIT**

Since many answers misunderstood my question let me clarify a bit. I don't have problem enabling prettyUrl nor hiding the index.php from URL. My problem is I cannot make URL with no query string at all just as I asked above

Answer (score 0):

In main.php

```
'components' => [
    ....
    'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => 'false'
    ],
```

Comment: this enables pretty url and hides index.php. I know all those but still my path have query string like `?view=myview&id=2` the issue I try to solve

Answer (score 0):

In config.php

```
'urlManager' => [ 
 'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 
 'showScriptName' => false, 
],
```

Comment: this enables pretty url and hides index.php. I know all those but still my path have query string like `?view=myview&id=2` the issue I try to solve

Answer (score 0):

In `config.php` add component

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
    ...
```

`.htaccess` file in web directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Also find detailed instructions here: http://fellowtuts.com/yii/creating-seo-friendly-url-in-yii-2-0-framework/ and don't forget to check related article links at the end for having SEO friendly URL.

EDIT: If I understood you correctly then you wish to use BaseUrl helper. You can write as follow:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

$path = 'forum/post/id/2014/make-yii2-work';
$url = Url::toRoute([$path]);

<!-- HTML -->
<a href="<?= $url; ?>">Make Yii 2 Work</a>
```

Where you can grab `$path` variable value from database.

Source:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#toRoute()-detail
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html

Comment: this enables pretty url and hides index.php. I know all those but still my path have query string like `?view=myview&id=2` the issue I try to solve

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My answer lays in terms of regexp. If your "route" (e.g. "controller/module") and "params" (e.g. "['id' => 23, 'slug' => 'some-slug']") didn't match anyone’s url rule in your config so than url manager will return you link as you wrote above ("some_route?view=myview&id=2")

Answer (score 0):

As @liding pointed in his answer when the parameters doesn't match your rules config they will be output in the url.

I have similar issue with login redirect - I redirect to a login page when the user session is gone, which has the same url format as the user dashboard page, e.g. mysite.com/user and mysite.com/user/peter and that will result in something similar to 'mysite.com/user/?slug='.

So to remove the "?slug" from the query string, in login controller I use:

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;
if ($request->get('slug')) {
    $queryParams = $request->getQueryParams();
    unset($queryParams['slug']);
    $request->setQueryParams($queryParams);
    $this->redirect(['site/login']);
}
```

If you want to remove all query params, you could probably just pass empty array to *setQueryParams* method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to([''])
```

to create a link to current page without query parameters or put whatever path you want in the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

To mask the query string you need to add **rules** to the url manager. The conversion is carried out based on the matched value. In the following example the id is masked, but you can still create more complex expressions with more parameters:

```
[
    'components' => [
        //...
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // RULES
            'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ],
        ]
        //...
    ]
];
```

For example *post/update?id=1* will be converted to *post/update/1*.

Per maggiori dettagli consulta l'api DOC ufficiale
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-rules